# Globalization difference in inline tags in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, globalization

Is there any advantage/downfalls between using the inline write tag instead of the resource tag? Example:

```
<%=Resources.Site.SampleString %>
```

The resources tag (expression tag) as seen in any MSDN example:

```
<asp:Literal id="Literal1" runat="server" text="<%$ Resources:Site, SampleString %>" />
```

I find the first option far easier to use, and it has IntelliSense, but maybe it won't function the same?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These methods will function exactly the same. The latter simply calls first one; there is a reason why strongly-typed resources access code is being generated in the background. Therefore you can use whatever method you please.

By the way, there is also another way - by using [meta:resourcekey attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228093%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). So you should be able to write:

```
<asp:Literal id="Literal1" runat="server"
             meta:resourcekey="SampleString" text="Default one" />
```

and it all should work exactly the same.

**EDIT** on implicit Localization.

What I forgot to mention, is that with meta:resourcekey certain conditions have to be met. The conditions are:

- Values are taken from App_LocalResources, therefore related resource file need to exist
- Related resource file name must be pagename.resx, for example: Default.aspx.resx, Default.aspx.es.resx
- The resource file must contain keys in form of resourcekey.propertyname, for example SampleString.Text, SampleString.ID (although I wouldn't localize control ID's)
- Because of how resources are generated, the key mentioned above must exist in invariant resource file (Default.aspx.resx), or it won't be localized.

Comment: Does this grab the value from the App_Global resources? (or local)

Comment: It is taken from App_LocalResources, implicit Localization regards to concrete pages. See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

I realised after some time that the `<%=Resources.Site.SampleString %>` method does not have designer support (which is understandable). This doesn't bother me, but it is a difference (for future readers).

So if you need or want designer support, the second option would be necessary.